# Can I insert custom attribute information into the MySQL content table?

Tags: mysql, content

I'd like to be able to give each article an additional attribute. Not sure if I can use the columns that exist in #_content. I'm concerned any modifications I do will be overwritten or cause errors. Is there an existing column in the table that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds exactly what the new custom fields (com_fields) are for.

(Content > fields)

If these don't work for you, can you expand your question to explain what you are trying to do differently.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Looks like it is only available in version 3.7 and up. Just had to make a small update. It's exactly what I needed. I'll need to see if the php store() function can directly write to the field when saving article data.